# What are ways to optimize this react app with potentially millions of components rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, optimization

Here is an example of what it does:
https://ostralyan.github.io/flood-fill/

This app is for educational purposes, and here is the [source code](https://github.com/Ostralyan/flood-fill/tree/master/src).

Right now, anything bigger than a 100x100 grid gives me performance issues. When I say performance issues I mean that when I click a cell there's a few seconds delay before it renders the next state.
My goal is to optimize this to support 1m squares (1000x1000).

Here is the algorithm I use for this approach

```
  floodFillIterative(i, j) {
    const oldColor = this.props.squares[i][j].color;
    const newColor = this.getUniqueRandomColor(oldColor);
    const squares = this.props.squares.slice();

    const stack = [
      [i, j]
    ];
    while (stack.length) {
      const squareCoordinates = stack.pop();
      let newI = squareCoordinates[0];
      let newJ = squareCoordinates[1];

      if (newI < 0 || newI >= this.props.squaresPerRow) continue;
      if (newJ < 0 || newJ >= this.props.squaresPerRow) continue;
      let nextSquare = squares[newI][newJ];

      if (nextSquare.color !== oldColor) continue;
      if (nextSquare.visited) continue;

      Array.prototype.push.apply(stack, [
        [newI - 1, newJ],
        [newI + 1, newJ],
        [newI, newJ - 1],
        [newI, newJ + 1],
      ]);
      nextSquare.visited = true;
      nextSquare.color = newColor;
    }
    this.setState({ squares });
    this.clearVisisted(squares);
  }
```

This algorithm runs in linear time so I'm not sure if optimizing the algorithm will really improve performance that much more. Although I'm open to any suggestions of optimization.

I also have a line of code here

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.color !== this.props.color) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

That prevents the squares to rerender if nothing about them have changed. I'm looking for any other way to optimize this app.

Thanks!

Comment: Dom will always have trouble updating so many elements. I would suggest you to use canvas and draw operations instead of dom

Comment: Great question. I think it will make every frontend framework bend as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great optimization challenge! The main problem is that each Square is a react component so you are creating a huge amount of elements to render in the DOM.

React is gonna naturally slow down in that case, even when using something like Redux or shouldComponentUpdate like you're using.

I would highly recommend creating a single component using an HTML Canvas for your board rendering instead of Square Components.

Here is a great codepen that is rendering a ton of pixels in realtime: `function drawAll()` https://codepen.io/gunderson/full/EyXBrr

And here's a good tutorial on building a board on a canvas:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164650/drawing-a-board-for-the-board-game-go-html-canvas